# Parse.com Role Base access not working

Tags: parse-platform, role, rbac

I am experiencing problems with accessing an object i created with role ACL. I created the object like this

```
var Enquiry = Parse.Object.extend("Enquiry");
var enquiry = new Enquiry();
enquiry.set("first", firstName);
enquiry.set("last", lastName);

var enquiryACL = new Parse.ACL();
enquiryACL.setRoleWriteAccess("XXX_User", true);
enquiryACL.setRoleReadAccess("XXX_User", true);
enquiry.setACL(enquiryACL);
enquiry.save();
```

I later on try to access the same object i created when a user of the role "XXX_User" is logged in

```
var Item = Parse.Object.extend("Enquiry");
var query = new Parse.Query(Item);

query.find({
    success : function(items) {
        displayItems(items);
    },
    error : function(error) {
        alert("couldn't display list: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

Now the problem is that the query doesn't return any rows even though i can see in the dashboard that the object is created. The ACL set for the enquiry objects is {"role:XXX_User":{"write":true,"read":true}}

I can see that there is a Role Object with name "XXX_User" in the data browser and i can also see that the user i log in with is shown when i click "View Relations" on the Role object in the data browser.

Is there anything i am missing? Any help on this is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem. It was not working because the role XXX_User i created was saved with public read access to be false. I had to make sure that the role is publicly readable and then it worked like a charm.